# Get json collection data to angular

Tags: angular

I have an angular project and a json file uploaded in a server. I need to get json data to my component.

Json file looks like this:

```
{ 
    "name":"AB", 
    "age":22, 
    "details": [
        {
            "country":"USA"
        },
        {
            "City":"LA"
        }
    ] 
}
```

I'm using http get method to call json file. I have this component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-filter',
    templateUrl: './filter.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./filter.component.css']
})
export class FilterComponent {

    name:string;

    constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { 
    this.httpClient.get('http://mywebdata/explore/jsonfile')
    .subscribe(
            (dat:any) => {
                this.name = dat.name;
            }
        )
    }

}
```

And the html :

```
<div>
    <p>{{name}} is total</p>
</div>
```

when I run the application, it shows only "is total" and no any error in console. What I missed here?

Comment: Probably name is undfined. You can try to `console.log(dat)` and see what it's returning. You might need to do a `JSON.parse(dat)`

Comment: what is the data of this.name?

Comment: Swoox: Console give the correct result. Then the error is on JSON parse?

Comment: Krishna Rathore: this.name is "AB" shows in the json object.

Comment: Your JSON is wrong, missing `:` after `age` field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a few problems here.

1. Your JSON is not valid.  You are missing a colon between your age name-value pair.
2. In the code below notice that I do data.json() and store it into a variable then use that variable. This puts the data into a JSONObject format that can be navigated using JSONPath syntax.

Additionally, notice the change from **(dat:any) =>** to **data =>**

Change your subscribe to the following:

```
.subscribe(
    data => {
      let responseJSON = data.json();

      console.log(responseJSON);
      this.name = responseJSON.name;
      console.log(this.name);
    });
```

Comment: This change gave me an error: " Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object' "

Comment: Sorry, I had a bad line in there. Can you try the edited code?

Answer (score 0):

To use JSON inside your file you need to deploy this file on your local server, in your case json file is not being loaded, That's why you are not able to retrieve data from JSON. Try this way once, add below code in `angular-cli.json`.

```
"apps": [
{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    { "glob": "jsonfile.json", "input": "./", "output": "./assets/" }
  ],..
```

or you can use following code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter',
  templateUrl: './filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter.component.css']
})
export class FilterComponent {
name:string;
constructor(private http:Http) { }

public getName(){
return this.http.get('http://mywebdata/explore/jsonfile')
  .map((response: Response) => {
    const data = response.json();
    this.name = data.name;
    return data.name;
  })
  .catch((error: Response) => {
    return Observable.throw('Something went wrong');
  });
}   
}
```